# Who can see which information about me on Patreon?

Tags: privacy, patreon

I'd like to support different projects on Patreon, but I am a bit concerned about different privacy aspects:

- Does the publisher see my username (when not participating in comments/forums on their page), e.g., for rewards or can I get the rewards anonymously for example as a gift code?
- Does he see my real name or even more data like credit card numbers or addresses, e.g., for tax reasons?
- Does my Patreon profile reveal which projects I am supporting?
- Can other patrons of a project see that I am supporting a project?
- Can other patrons of one project see which other projects I am supporting?

I guess one solution for separating the usernames would be to create multiple accounts, but I am really curious about what information the publisher sees about me.

In general I try to leave little real data, but I guess for financial sites it is hard to completely avoid it, except when they accept crypto currencies or other more anonymous payment methods.
I do not need bullet proof security, but I would like to reduce the amount of personal data that is visible to publishers and other users.